# Reverse dimensions in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to reverse the current way my loops works. currently, I have a set of loans and the loop does calculations to each loan for k number of periods before moving to the next loan. I need to reverse this and for each period, do all the calculations to all the loans and then move to the next period.

I've attached the current code below. instead of looping through each loan (as it does now). I need the code to first loop through each period and in every period,do the calculations.

I have tried reversing the loops by doing the following but I think I'm missing something. the problem is  that the original way, i didn't have to look at values of other loans for each period. but the new way, for each loan i need to be able to reference previous period's values and I don't know if something as simple as NotionalEndBal(z, k - 1) will work?

Any thoughts/hints/references are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
'   Loop through each loan
    For k = 0 To TotalPeriods

'   Clear the notional amort arrays
        For q = 0 To TotalLoans1
            NotionalBegBal(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalPMT(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalInt(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalPrin(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalEndBal(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalAmortFact(q, 0) = 0
            CurRateArray(q, 0) = 0
        Next q

'   Begin the notional amortization with the zero period balance and the amort factor set to
'   one
        For z = 1 To TotalLoans1
            If k = 0 Then
                NotionalEndBal(z, 0) = gp1CurBalArray(z, 0)
                NotionalAmortFact(z, 0) = 1
                Else
                    NotionalBegBal(z, 0) = NotionalEndBal(z, k - 1)


' original code below

  '   Loop through each loan
    For k = 1 To TotalLoans1

'   Clear the notional amort arrays
        For q = 0 To TotalPeriods
            NotionalBegBal(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalPMT(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalInt(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalPrin(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalEndBal(q, 0) = 0
            NotionalAmortFact(q, 0) = 0
            CurRateArray(q, 0) = 0
        Next q

'   Begin the notional amortization with the zero period balance and the amort factor set to
'   one
        For z = 0 To TotalPeriods
            If z = 0 Then
                NotionalEndBal(z, 0) = gp1CurBalArray(k, 0)
                NotionalAmortFact(z, 0) = 1
                Else
                    NotionalBegBal(z, 0) = NotionalEndBal(z - 1, 0)

'   Determine the current period interest rate.  If fixed rate use given rate, otherwise
'   variable tests need to be run
                    If FixedFloat = "Fixed" Then
                        CurRateArray(z, 0) = gp1FxdRateArray(k, 0)
                        Else

'   Floating rate assets in the first period use the introductory interest rate
                            If z = 1 Then
                                CurRateArray(z, 0) = gp1IntroRateArray(k, 0)
                                Else
'   Floating rate assets at their first reset are bound by the initial cap
                                    If z = gp1ResetFreqArray(k, 0) Then
                                        CurRateArray(z, 0) = min(gp1AssetFloatArray(z, _
                                        gp1IndexArray(k, 0)) + gp1MarginArray(k, 0), _
                                        CurRateArray(z - 1, 0) + gp1InitCapArray(k, 0), _
                                        gp1CeilingArray(k, 0))
                                        Else
'   Otherwise the assets are bound by the subsequent cap and the ceiling
                                            If z Mod gp1ResetFreqArray(k, 0) = 0 Then
                                                CurRateArray(z, 0) = min(gp1AssetFloatArray(z, _
                                                gp1IndexArray(k, 0)) + gp1MarginArray(k, 0), _
                                                CurRateArray(z - 1, 0) + gp1SubCapArray(k, 0), _
                                                gp1CeilingArray(k, 0))
                                                Else
                                                    CurRateArray(z, 0) = CurRateArray(z - 1, 0)
                                            End If
                                    End If
                            End If
                    End If

'   If the payment is already provided then use it, otherwise calculate it based on
'   Original Term, Rate, and Balance
                    If gp1ProvPmtArray(k, 0) > 0 Then
                        NotionalPMT(z, 0) = min(gp1ProvPmtArray(k, 0), _
                        NotionalBegBal(z, 0) + (CurRateArray(z, 0) * _
                        DayFactorArray(z, 0)) * NotionalBegBal(z, 0))
                        Else
                            NotionalPMT(z, 0) = min(VBA.Pmt(CurRateArray(z, 0) * _
                            DayFactorArray(z, 0), gp1OrgTermArray(k, 0), gp1OrgBalArray(k, 0) * -1), _
                            NotionalBegBal(z, 0) + (CurRateArray(z, 0) * _
                            DayFactorArray(z, 0)) * NotionalBegBal(z, 0))
                    End If

'   Pay notional interest
                    NotionalInt(z, 0) = (CurRateArray(z, 0) * DayFactorArray(z, 0)) _
                    * NotionalBegBal(z, 0)

'   Check if loan is in an interest only period, if so do not pay principal.  Otherwise
'   principal is payment less interest
                    If z <= gp1IOPdsArray(k, 0) Then
                        NotionalPrin(z, 0) = 0
                        Else
                        NotionalPrin(z, 0) = NotionalPMT(z, 0) - _
                        NotionalInt(z, 0)
                    End If

'   Calculate ending balance and amortization factor
                        NotionalEndBal(z, 0) = NotionalBegBal(z, 0) - _
                        NotionalPrin(z, 0)
                        NotionalAmortFact(z, 0) = NotionalEndBal(z, 0) / _
                        NotionalEndBal(0, 0)
            End If
        Next z
next k
```

Comment: Are you sure this is VBA? I'm quite sure you need `Next` and `End if` or the code does not run.

Comment: hi, updated the code to show the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro.

If I could understand you and what you need is just invert the for loops, take a look at the code below, I think it can help you.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim total As Integer

    total = 3

    ' NORMAL FOR
    For i = 1 To total
        MsgBox i
    Next

    ' INVERTED FOR
    For i = total To 1 Step -1
        MsgBox i
    Next
End Sub
```